# moveRowAtIndexPath and CoreData Relationships

Tags: xcode, core-data, uitableview

I'm stuck at ordering Core Data relationships. I have a to-many relationship but the problem I can't overcome is that re-ordering relational entities in one view re-orders them in every view they belong to.

Example: `People` are added to `activity1` and are randomly ordered using the `moveRowAtIndexPath` method. Those same people get added to `activity2` and are ordered identically to `activity1`. How can I stop this?

Relevant code:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    NSUInteger fromRow = [fromIndexPath row];
    NSUInteger toRow = [toIndexPath row];

    id object = [[eventAthletes objectAtIndex:fromRow] retain];
    [eventAthletes removeObjectAtIndex:fromRow];
    [eventAthletes insertObject:object atIndex:toRow];

    int i = 0;
    for (object in eventAthletes)
    {
        [object setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i++] forKey:@"athleteDisplayOrder"];
    }

    [self saveContext];

    [object release];
}
```

I updated the model and made the attribute `athleteDisplayOrder` transient thinking that by using the key and NOT saving it, I would be able to start fresh in a new event. No Dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identical ordering is expected behavior. If you want to "randomize" the order, you have to explicitly do that by reassigning random `athleteDisplayOrder`attributes.

**EDIT:**

If you want to have a special user definable order of athletes for each event one way to solve this is to create a new entity `EventAthletes` that has to-one relationships both Event and Athlete and also contains a display order attribute.

**END EDIT**

BTW, you are using an extra data array with core data for display in a table view. Did you know that you can use `NSFetchedResultsController` to manage your table view datasource much more efficiently?

Comment: I'm not using NSFetchedResultsController here because the MC was passed to the view when it loaded. In viewDidLoad I call    NSMutableArray *sortedAthletes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[event.eventAthletes allObjects]];
 [sortedAthletes sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
 self.eventAthletes = sortedAthletes; and only work with the relationship in this view. At this stage, an event exists, athletes have been assigned to said event, and I want to give the end user the ability to order the athletes. Problem I'm running into is the ordered athlete keeps that order on every event.

Comment: I was hoping there was a simpler way but this is what I figured. Thank you so much for helping!